# uses of html attribute "ref" in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

What are the use cases which require the use of the HTML attribute `ref`?
And what would be the value affected to it?

I've faced this example:

```js
methods: {
  myMethod(event) {
    this.$refs.userInfo.open(); 
  },
}
```

```html
<template>
  <myComponent
    ref="userInfo"
    :usr="usr" />
</template>
```

So my question what is **userInfo** really is?
From where comes **open** method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs) is a way of accessing the element itself in the DOM.
It's usually used to make some DOM-specific things or to handle some edge-cases (like a vanilla JS package not fully compatible with Vue's reactivity).

If not needed, you could use regular [event listeners](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#listening-to-events) + [iterations with `v-for`s](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for).

In your given example, you're accessing either a component `userInfo` or a method/object with a public method of `open`. I recommend that you inspect your DOM tree in your Vue devtools.

Comment: to render a child component inside parent component is it required to use ref attribute ?

Comment: @alinerenault I'd say no but I guess that it depends on what package you're using/what you want to achieve.